# Запросить доступ

Tags: android

Как запросить "Доступ к статистике использования" ?

Я так понимаю если просто зайти в этот пункт меню то там нет посторонних приложений кто не запрашивал для него доступ.
Так как приложению получить разрешение от пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

Нашел как)